# Geometry, Mensuration

Tags: geometry, triangles

If the diagonal BC passes through center of the circle, then the area of the shaded region in the given figure is
\begin{align*} a)\quad &\dfrac{a^2}{2(3-\pi)}\\
 b) \quad &\dfrac{a^2}{\frac{\pi}{2}-1}\\
 c) \quad &2a^2(\pi-1)\\
 d) \quad &\dfrac{a^2}{2(\frac{\pi}{2}-1)}
\end{align*}

[image: The Equilateral Circle circumscribed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the area of the circle? If the line $BC$ passes through the center of the circle, what area is on either half of the line? And finally, what is the area of the triangle?

Comment: Area of circle is πr^2 hence here it is π*(BC/2)^2 and Equilateral triangle area is √3/4 a^2. I am a novice in maths and can't figure out how to find the area shaded. Do we use the semicircle formula and subtract the area of the triangle from it?

Comment: @AmeethVPai Since the line $BC$ passes through the center of the circle, either side of the line has area of half of the entire circle. Because of this, we need only to calculate half of the area of the circle, (this will be the area of the triangle and the shaded region) and then subtract the area of the triangle (to achieve the area of the shaded region).

Comment: @Ameeth The triangle is NOT equilateral. Because $BC$ is a diameter, you actually have $\angle BAC$ is right due to inscribed angles.

Comment: @Hao Sorry my mistake. I realized that when I did the problem